# Add column admin order list Woocommerce with sequential number

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

what is the method for add a column in the admin order list with a simple sequential number?

Just add a column with 1 / 2 / 3 / 4 for the single order, just for have a quick view about the number of order with a filter active.

I try with a plugin but I think I need to modify the WooCommerce file of the theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order_id in WooCommerce is the id in wp_posts table which is used for many things, posts, pages, orders ... That's why the order ids are rarely in sequence.
This means you have to add a separate sequence and keep track of it.
There is a plugin that does exactly that:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wt-woocommerce-sequential-order-numbers/

You can configure it to use a numbered sequence or any other custom sequence.

The plugin is storing data into "_order_number"  postmeta and replaces the original first column content, like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqau2.png)

If you want to see this sequence number in a separate column then you can use a plugin like: https://wordpress.org/plugins/codepress-admin-columns/
to add a custom column with the order number

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crK12.png)

EDIT: Adding code snippet to show sequential numbers in the first column.

```
function custom_columns_head_only_shop_order( $columns ) {
    $new_columns = array( 'sequential_number' => 'Sequential Number' );
    $columns = array_merge( $new_columns, $columns );
    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'custom_columns_head_only_shop_order', 10 );


function custom_columns_content_only_shop_order( $column_name ) {
    if ( $column_name == 'sequential_number' ) {
        $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
        $per_page = get_query_var( 'posts_per_page' );
        $offset = ( $paged - 1 ) * $per_page;

        global $sequential_number_counter;
        if ( ! isset( $sequential_number_counter ) ) {
            $sequential_number_counter = 0;
        }
        $sequential_number_counter++;
        echo $offset + $sequential_number_counter;
    }
}
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'custom_columns_content_only_shop_order', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Thanks Ivo for the fast reply. So there is no method to have this number not connected with the number of the order? 
I mean for me it's not important change the order number, but have this sequential number when I filter the order list, for see the exact number of order immediately.

Comment: Hi Andrew, with the plugin I linked you can set this sequence independently, it can be 1,2,3. That sequence is completely separated from the original order_id. Then you can use the Admin columns plugin to show this number in a separate column, see the fully detailed description here: https://bytflow.com/how-to-add-a-sequence-number-to-woocommerce-order/ 
Unfortunately, the first plugin doesn't have an option to leave the order number intact. They fully integrated it which is something that you may not want to do. As an alternative, you could ditch the plugin and create the sequence yourself.

Comment: In a diy/code snippet approach, you would use the 'woocommerce_new_order' hook to create a custom post meta for your custom sequence, for example:

add_action('woocommerce_new_order', function ($order_id) {
     //  do a query to find the largest existing custom sequence number
    // increase the number and store as the postmeta to new order
    
}, 10, 1);

Then you can use the Admin Columns plugin to display your custom postmeta sequence. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Hi Andrew, did you solve the issue?

Comment: Hi Ivo, sorry for the late reply. Unfortunately not, with your method I add a sequential number and this is good, but after the activation of a filter I have always the same number (of course) but we want to see the number of the stripes immediatly in the order list. I think it's not simple, after the filter, have a count of the stripes selected.

Comment: Oh, I see, you want to have 1,2,3... every time? For example, you are on the first page of orders, table starts with 1,2,3. Then you go to 2nd page, table starts with 1,2,3 and not with 21,22,23. You filter by customer and there are 5 orders,  the number starts from 1 again. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, is exactly this. The filter is add with a plugin AdminColumns, when i selected one field with "Yes", i have the only order with this data. Here i need to see the number, so the administrator understand what number of order have this data. Thanks for the patience

Comment: Hi Andrew, check the updated answer, under the "EDIT"

Comment: Hi Ivo, I'm sorry for the late respond.
BUT YOU DID IT! this is exactly what I search, I don't have enough thanks to say to you. 
You made my day!

Comment: Hi Andrew, no problem, it's a holiday season, we are all a bit slower these days :)
I am really happy to see that my small code snippet helped you!